# Adding generated content to jQuery object which is not bound to the DOM fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically append an HTML-snippet to an existing Element with `.append`.

Somehow, the HTML String which was created by the script is not appended to the element.

The element which is appended to is not hooked into the DOM at the moment when the snippet is appended.

All of it is encapsulated in a JavaScript function. Here is the code:

```
append_content = function() {
    var elem = $('<li><div>some text</div></li>');
    var somecontent = get_content();  // returns a string: '<div>xx</div>'
    elem.append('<div>bleh1</div>');
    elem.append(somecontent);
    elem.append('<div>bleh2</div>');
    console.log(elem);
    return elem;
}
```

The log contains all items correctly, like:

```
<li>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>bleh1</div>
    <div>xx</div>
    <div>bleh2</div>
</li>
```

But when im hooking the elem to the DOM later on, the content of the function call is gone.  I.e. it is not visible in the computed source (neither in FireBug nor Chrome development tools).

It looks like this:

```
<li>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>bleh1</div>
    <div>bleh2</div>
</li>
```

I am almost convinced that I have some scope issues or something like that here, but I don't get it. There is no error message in the console. Any advice?

### Update

Indeed, this was a self-made problem. Striipng down the code for an examle to post here made me realize that i called a similar function wihtout the function call mentioned above - silly me. Thanks for all the comments and help.

Comment: This should work just fine; http://jsfiddle.net/v25Da/. Can you show a snippet which demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: Your element isn't the `<li>` anything that is appended is added after the `<li>` element resulting in the above comment demo

Comment: You will need to show us more code, for example the part where you "hook the elem to the DOM later on". What you provided us works.

Comment: I prefer to do append and element creation in plain javascript.

Comment: @jonathandey: Why would you think so? [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is not [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: Is the code for `get_content` as simple as `return '<div>xx</div>';` or is it something else. If so, can yuo post it.

Comment: I edited the fiddle to represent the situation some more: http://jsfiddle.net/v25Da/1/, but it works perfect. It also works, if i call the function manually on the dev-console. I'll try to make a sample out of my real code here that shows the faulty behaviour and post it here.

Comment: Based on your working example posted in your comment, I don't see how it is not the `get_content()` call.

Comment: @Bergi ah very true! having one of them days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks correct to me - I'd check the output of the get_content() method to ensure it is in fact returning valid html.  Check it using alert("somecontent") as well as console - console.log only writes out the first line of XML in firebug - not sure about chrome...

Comment: Not sure it is the `get_content()` as such cause `console.log(elem)` writes out the expected items. Could it be a race condition whereby the `get_content()` has a slight delay coming back while append continues? Not sure if that would even be possible or not. Just putting it out there.

Comment: Slight delay?  Is it asynchronous?  If so, that's your problem.  AJAX calls don't block and wait.  Execution continues.

Comment: Correct answer, the script works just fine in this version. I stripped it down to a bare minimum to match the scenario in my application, but it still works. I'll search further to reproduce the problem and post another question.